# Jsoup.parse().text() add not desired whitespace

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to clean a String removing all html tags from it, so this is my code:

```
System.out.println("Result:" + Jsoup.parse("Dani<div></div>el").text());
```

the result is

```
Result:Dani el
```

instead should be `Result:Daniel`

Following Jsoup code I see that the "problem" is in org.jsoup.nodes.Element in this method:

```
public String text() {
    final StringBuilder accum = new StringBuilder();
    new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;
                appendNormalisedText(accum, textNode);
            } else if (node instanceof Element) {
                Element element = (Element) node;
                if (accum.length() > 0 &&
                    (element.isBlock() || element.tag.getName().equals("br")) &&
                    !TextNode.lastCharIsWhitespace(accum))
                    accum.append(" ");
            }
        }

        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
        }
    }).traverse(this);
    return accum.toString().trim();
}
```

when at some apoint there is `accum.append(" ");`. 
Is clear that in some circustances is convenient that a block html tag add a space in the corresponding text version; but in some cases this is not true.
In my case infact the result is wrong.

I think would be good that text() method have a boolean parameter `preserveWhiteSpaces` that enable or disable the execution of the line `accum.append(" ");`.
I hope some developer of Jsoup can consider this request: I seen that also others people has this problem with whitespaces.

If someone has some good idea to solve the problem without change the Jsoup sources is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to clean a String removing all html tags from it,

You want to use the `clean()` method.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
System.out.println("Result:" + Jsoup.clean("Dani<div></div>el", Whitelist.none()));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Result:Daniel
```

---

> In my case however the result is wrong. Do you have some suggestion to solve this problem?

You can instanciate a `NodeTraversor` with a custom `NodeVisitor`.

Just to give you an idea:

```
private static String toText(Element element) {
    final StringBuilder accum = new StringBuilder();
    new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {
        public void head(Node node, int depth) {
            if (node instanceof TextNode) {
                TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;
                accum.append(textNode.getWholeText());
            } else if (node instanceof Element) {
                // Do nothing ...
            }
        }

        public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
        }
    }).traverse(element);

    return accum.toString().trim();
}
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Result:" + toText(Jsoup.parse("Dani<div></div>el")));
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Result:Daniel
```

Comment: Sure, this is what is needed but I should change Jsoup sources and build it for my project....maybe not so convenient. Would be much better that toText() method has a boolean parameter "preserveWhiteSpaces" that enable or disable the execution of the line  accum.append(" ");

Comment: @drenda Check my update. I think what you need is a the `Whitelist.none()` object. See first sample code in my answer.